# Javascript recursion return undefined instead of value that set when hit the base case

Tags: javascript, recursion

I try to do a recursion that can hit the base case and return the value back. I found that the solution which required to return the function in order to get back the value but not exactly sure why to work in this way?

```
// Test one
var tracker = 0;
var executeMe = function() {
   tracker++;
   if(tracker === 2) {
      return 'hits 2';
   }
   executeMe();
}
executeMe(); 
// return undefined ?

// Test two
var tracker = 0;
var executeMe = function() {
   tracker++;
   if(tracker === 2) {
      return 'hits 2';
   }
   return executeMe();
}
executeMe(); 
// return 'hits 2' ?
```

Comment: `return executeMe();`

Comment: In your first example, when you reach the bottom of the tree, you return `hits 2`. However in the level above that, you don't return a value from your function, so the final result of `executeMe()` is `undefined`. In your second example you have fixed that problem.

Comment: this is a matter of scopes. Your console is asking for the result of `executeMe()` in the top scope. executeMe(), in it's inner scope, retreives and _throws away_ those values. The result is the top scope (the only one whose value you're tracking), returns nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can probably visualize is with something like this (same indentation level denotes the execution of the same function call:

```
calling executeMe() - with tracker 0

    Ignored If Statement
    calling nested executeMe() - with tracker 1

        Ignored If Statement
        calling nested executeMe() - with tracker 2
        Caught Base case with return 2

    Got return 2 but unused, returning Nothing (undefined)

Got return undefined but unused, returning Nothing (undefined)
```